# Angularjs - ng-route not working on IE9 - the views are not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, coldfusion

I'm a beginner with Angularjs. I'm going to develop an application with this framework and Coldfusion for retrieving data from the database.

I have a problem with the compatibility on IE9 (mandatory and used by default in my office). All works in Chrome and Firefox, and I do not know why the application does not work on IE9.

The view is not shown when you click on the button in the top menu (in order to display all contacts or the view with the form foradding a contact). I think that it's a problem with the "ng-route" dependency, but I'm not sure.

I'm using the version AngularJS v1.2.23 and the dependency "ng-route" (angular-route.min.js).

**here my code**:

- index.html

  ```
  <html ng-app="ContactsApp" class="ng-app:ContactsApp" id="ng-app">

      <head>

          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
          <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
          <title>Application</title> 
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap-3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap-3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/select.css" rel="stylesheet">     
      </head>  
      <body>

          <div class="container">
              <div class="spacer navbar">

                  <h1 class="nav nav-pills navbar-left">Application</h1>

                  <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right" data-ng-controller="NavbarController">
                      <li data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/all-contacts')}"><a href="#/all-contacts">All contacts</a></li>
                      <li data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/add-contacts')}"><a href="#/add-contacts">Add contacts</a></li>
                  </ul>

              </div>        

              <div ng-view></div>

              <hr/>

              <div class="footer">
                  <p>@Copy right 2014</p>
              </div>

        </div>

        <script src="lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>              
        <script src="lib/js/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script>              
        <script src="lib/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>          
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/appService.js"></script>                
      </body>
  </html>
  ```
- app.js (controller)

  ```
  var app=angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);    
  app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider.when('/all-contacts',
      {
        templateUrl: 'template/allContacts.html',
        controller: 'ctrlContacts'        
      })
      .when('/view-contacts/:contactId',
      {
        templateUrl: 'template/viewContact.html',
        controller: 'ctrlViewContacts'
      })
      .when('/search-contacts',
      {
        templateUrl: 'template/fastSearch.html',
        controller: 'ctrlContactSearch'
      })  
      .when('/add-contacts',
      {
        templateUrl: 'template/manageContact.html',
        controller: 'ctrlAddContacts'
      }) 
      .otherwise({redirectTo:'/all-contacts'});  
  });    

  app.controller('ctrlContacts', function ($scope, ContactService){
      $scope.contacts=null;
      $scope.search = function(searchText) {
          if (searchText.length>2) {
              ContactService.fastSearch(searchText).success(function(contacts){
                  $scope.contacts = contacts; 
              }); 
          }else{
              $scope.contacts=null;
          }
      }   

      // recherche   
      $scope.searchText = null;
      $scope.razRecherche = function() {
          $scope.searchText = null;
      }   

      // tri   
      $scope.champTri = null;
      $scope.triDescendant = false;
      $scope.triEmails = function(champ) {
          if ($scope.champTri == champ) {
              $scope.triDescendant = !$scope.triDescendant;
          } else {
              $scope.champTri = champ;
              $scope.triDescendant = false;
          }   
      }

      $scope.cssChevronsTri = function(champ) {
          return {
              glyphicon: $scope.champTri == champ,
              'glyphicon-chevron-up' : $scope.champTri == champ && !$scope.triDescendant,
              'glyphicon-chevron-down' : $scope.champTri == champ && $scope.triDescendant 
          };
      }

      $scope.confirmDel = function (id) {
          if(confirm('Do you want to delete this contact?')){
              ContactService.delContact(id).success(function(){
                  ContactService.getContact().success(function(contacts){
                      $scope.contacts = contacts; 
                  });             
              });
          }
          $scope.orderby = orderby;
      };

      $scope.setOrder = function (orderby) {
          if(orderby === $scope.orderby){
              $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
          }
          $scope.orderby = orderby;
      };

  });

  app.controller('NavbarController', function($scope, $location){
      $scope.getClass=function(path){

          if($location.path().substr(0,path.length) == path){
              return true;
          }else{
              return false;
          }

      }
  });

  ...
  ```
- appService.js

  ```
      app.factory('ContactService', function($http){
          var factory={};

          factory.getContact=function(id){
              return $http.get('http://dev.remede.eurostat.cec/amadese/AngularVersion/contacts.cfc?method=getContacts&subsString=' + id);
          };

          factory.loadPersonById=function(id){
              return $http.get('http://dev.remede.eurostat.cec/amadese/AngularVersion/contacts.cfc?method=loadPersonById&idPerson=' + id);
          };  

          factory.loadCategory=function(id){
              return $http.get('http://dev.remede.eurostat.cec/amadese/AngularVersion/categories.cfc?method=loadCategory&typeContact=' + id);
          };  

          factory.getCountry=function(id){
              return $http.get('http://dev.remede.eurostat.cec/amadese/AngularVersion/countries.cfc?method=getCountries&countryid=' + id);
          };

          factory.fastSearch=function(string){
              if (string){
                  chaine='http://dev.remede.eurostat.cec/amadese/AngularVersion/contacts.cfc?method=fastSearch&subsString=' + string;     
              }else{
                  chaine='';      
              }
              //alert(chaine);
              return $http.get(chaine);
          };

          factory.addNewPerson=function(objContact){
              //alert(objContact);
              return $http.get('http://dev.remede.eurostat.cec/amadese/AngularVersion/contacts.cfc?method=addNewPerson&jsStruct=' + JSON.stringify(objContact))
          };  

          return factory;
      })
  ```
- allContacts.html (view)

  ```
  <h4>View all contacts</h4>

  <table ng-show="contacts.length"  class="table table-striped table-hover spacer">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th class="colPerson">
                  <a ng-click="triEmails('PERSON')">Person</a>
                  <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('PERSON')"></span>
              </th>
              <th class="colCompany">
                  <a ng-click="triEmails('COMPANY')">Company</a>
                  <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('COMPANY')"></span>
              </th>
              <th class="colDate">
                  <a ng-click="triEmails('REQUESTTRUEDATE')">Date</a>
                  <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('REQUESTTRUEDATE')"></span>
              </th>
              <th class="colDescription">
                  <a ng-click="triEmails('REQUESTDESCRIPTION')">Description</a>
                  <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('REQUESTDESCRIPTION')"></span>
              </th>
              <th class="colAction">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>       
        <tbody>     
          <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchText | orderBy:champTri:triDescendant" class="clickable">
          <td><a href="#/view-contacts/{{contact.ID}}">{{contact.PERSON}}</a></td>
          <td>{{contact.COMPANY}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.REQUESTTRUEDATE}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.REQUESTDESCRIPTION}}</td>     

          <td style="min-width100px;">
          <a href="#/edit-contacts/{{contact.ID}}" class="inline btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> 
          <button class="inline btn btn-default" data-ng-click="confirmDelPerson(contact.ID)">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
          </button>        
          </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody> 
      </table>
      <div ng-show="busy">Loading data...</div>
    </div>
  ```

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why is this tagged as 'ColdFusion'?

Comment: The file appService.js contains functions allowing to retrieve data from the database thanks to cfc files

Comment: Have you tried removing the # from the links in the <a href...> tags?

Comment: Yes,but it doesn't work anymore on all browser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the solution by adding the following "meta" tag in the "head" part of the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

With this tag, all works now perfectly in IE9.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are the man! I was sweating after my entire app wasnt working in IE9.

Comment: WHAT ?!   Errr, thank you... that beautifully fixed my Angular routing issue with IE11, but what the hell ?!   Hmmm...  there is a reason why us developers prefer using Chrome.... ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem where I just got a blank page in IE 9.  In chrome, FF and IE 10 and 11 routing worked fine and the first page of my app, the login page, would appear.  I tried the meta tag but it did not fix the issue. I also tried moving ng-app to the body tag.  Still didn't fix it.  One other strange thing was when I opened IE developer tools suddenly it would work and my login page would appear. I did some additional searching and found that using console.log anywhere in the JavaScript can cause issues in IE.  Once I removed all console.log calls in JS files, added the meta tag and moved ng-app to the body tag, routing worked on IE 9 in both standard and compatibility mode.

Comment: I've had this issue as well ... **console.log** and IE!

Comment: Wow,Thank you. This worked! This is the weirdest issue I ever encountered.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a shot in the dark but I have seen it happen before ..

Try moving

ng-app="ContactsApp" class="ng-app:ContactsApp" id="ng-app"

To the body tag and not the html tag

I don't know why this happens but I have had a similar issue, moving the tag to the body fixed it for me

Comment: Hi,Many thanks for the reply. Nevertheless I have tried this, and the problem is still present on IE9. On IE10 and IE11, all works.

Comment: Hi ( again ;-) )

can't reproduce bug in [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kRvDVE4x29Zfg9NTPXcZ?p=preview) with compatibility mode IE9

can you try it with your web browser?

Comment: Hi, I tested on my browser IE9 and when I click on your link "plunkr", a pop appears and displays "xdomain (http://plnkr.co): requires 'JSON' and this browser does not support it." The website is displayed but nothing appears, no code. This message has never been displayed before. I will test in IE 10 and IE11 with the compatibility mode.