# Angular JS/Bootstrap App routing not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am building my first Angular and Bootstrap application. For some reason the routing does not work with the partials in Internet Explorer. When I check the console in IE there are no errors. My code is:

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','mainControl','ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']);

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/splash', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/splash2.html',
    controller: 'MainControl'
}).
when('/advice', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/advice.html',
    controller: 'MainControl'
}).
when('/media', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/media.html',
    controller: 'MainControl'
}).
when('/main', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
    controller: 'MainControl'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/splash'
});
```

}]);

The angular versions I am using are:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

I also have a controller but I am guessing the problem is in app.js?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Which version of script and IE? Because some jQuery, Bootstrap versions do not support old IE.

Comment: In IE9 its not working.... which versions should I be using?

Comment: IE9 is alright, try checking the console for errors?

Comment: No errors the app loads but the partials don't?

Comment: It looks like it's a problem because none of the IE's work

Comment: Just to check it... does it work in Chrome? Or Safari?

Comment: Chrome and firefox are fine.... Safari and IE are not...

Answer (score 0):

"AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier."

[Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Maybe the problem is in the compatibility?

Comment: I recommend you to use angular ui-router:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router .
I am doing it all the time and it works well

Comment: Is IE not compatible with ngRoute?

Comment: try use this
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
Also, you can read more here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140575/angularjs-ng-route-not-working-on-ie9-the-views-are-not-displayed

Comment: It turns out its not a routing problem after all ui-router and ngRoute were fine, I have some code which is breaking it in two of the browsers