# angular routing ie9 error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, internet-explorer-9

In IE9 my angular routing does not work and it redirects me to whatever was before the '#' hashtag.

mysite.com/#/info -> mysite.com

even if i manually removes the /# from the URL and try again, i still get redirected.

It appends '#' to my URL because  html5 mode uses History API when the browser supports it, and falls back to *'hashbang'* (#) when it is not supported(like IE9).

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
  .state('statistics', {
      url: "/path/:myId",
      templateUrl: '../some/path/site.html',
      controller: 'Ctrl'
  }
);
```

been looking at various solutions such as:

- [AngularJS How to remove # symbol in IE9 by using route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829991/angularjs-how-to-remove-symbol-in-ie9-by-using-route)
- https://gist.github.com/thomseddon/3834721

but neither of them are working for me.

I'm looking for a solution without having to deactivate html5mode. Anyone experienced similar issue and managed to fix?

Comment: Refer this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140575/angularjs-ng-route-not-working-on-ie9-the-views-are-not-displayed

Comment: @TekriwalD already added meta tag, ng-app in body, no console logs :/ its not really the same issue either.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 mode, there are three situations in which the A tag is not rewritten: from the angular docs -
     1 Links that contain a target attribute. Example: link
     2 Absolute links that point to a different domain  Example: [link](http://angularjs.org/)
     3 Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base is defined Example: [link](/not-my-base/link)

You can try to use a global directive like this that add target='_self' to all all links without target.

```
myApp.directive('a', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (!attrs['target']) {
            element.attr('target', '_self');
        }
    }
}
}]);
```