# AngularJs ng-route not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm a beginner to AngularJs and currently working on a small test project. I found out the app perfectly working fine on Firefox but not in IE 11 and Chrome. I've been trying most of the fixes in the internet. adding meta tags and all but none of them worked for me. Here's my code.

**Code**

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/services', {
    templateUrl: 'services.html',
    controller: 'ServicesCtrl'
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/clients', {
    templateUrl: 'clients.html',
    controller: 'ClientsCtrl'
  });
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirecTo: '/'});
}]);

app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'Welcome to Inspire';
}]);

app.controller('ServicesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
}]);

app.controller('ClientsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'These are clients';
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#/services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#/clients">Clients</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try to put <script> tag inside <head>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs - ng-route not working on IE9 - the views are not displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140575/angularjs-ng-route-not-working-on-ie9-the-views-are-not-displayed)

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend you run through
Codeacademy.com
and
Udacity's front-end nano-degree(it's free if you scroll down and start on supporting courses).
https://www.udacity.com/course/front-end-web-developer-nanodegree--nd001

I see a lot of bad practice in the code snippets above and I don't recommend you start learning a framework until you feel comfortable with HTML/CSS and JavaScript.Once you do that you should then try picking up Angular.

As for your answer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#/services">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#/clients">Clients</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div ng-view=""></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll also have to install ng-Route https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute. Check this out for details. Again please don't continue to learn Angular. You NEED to understand JavaScript and best practices before you continue with a framework.
Go through those two places I recommended and you should be okay.